# Same icon behave differently for different project notification android

Tags: android, notifications, icons

I use same notification icon for two different projects for firebase notifcation. in one project the icon comes as it is but in other project it turns white for notification. Please help

Comment: Post the code for further research on developers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code Implementation of Notification Builder for below and above Lollipop OS version would be:

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_transperent);
} else { 
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
} 
If you want to set colored single icon for all OS version then

Solution: For colored icons, use

defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.your.app.pkj"
        minSdkVersion xx
        targetSdkVersion 20 // < 21 (target sdk version in manifest file will be less than 21).
        versionCode x
        versionName "x.x"
    }
```

in app/build.gradle file. It will solve your problem completely!! I have solve my issues by this code.

Comment: Thank you sanjeev for the answer. After your answer I noticed the targetSdkVersion were different in those two projects.When I setthe targetSdkVersion to above 20 in the working project it also started working differently

Comment: if my answer helped to solve the problem, then please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's a problem with the size of image/icon resize the image/icon size.

## I used following code to generate the Notification

```
public void showNotification(Context context) {
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setContentTitle("Notification")
                    .setContentText("Notify!!!");
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: Thanks Guru.Will the above code run when the app is in the background.

Comment: you are welcome. No! , If you want to run in background put this in Service